# Can one thread initiate async IO but another thread run the completion handler, etc

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost-asio, coroutine

I am exploring options for converting a multithreaded C++ application to an asynchronous style of networking, based on boost asio and completion handlers. However there are two sticking points:

1. Can one thread make an async write but another thread run its completion handler? The first thread belongs to a framework (and therefore cannot be part of the async thread pool) but is the only thread that can create work. The framework thread also makes the async write to a socket, but it immediately returns to running framework code, and is therefore unavailable. The second thread is created by my code is thus available to run the completion handler. Does boost asio have a way for the framework thread to initiate asynchronous IO but another thread run the resulting completion handler?
2. If the async model does not draw a distinction between compute and IO threads and threads aren't preemptible (unless we are using coroutines) isn't there a real possibility that an IO completion handler, e.g. read, can be indefinitely prevented from running by threads doing compute?

---

Following [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059605/can-one-thread-initiate-async-io-but-another-thread-run-the-completion-handler#comment134169787_76065929) to @sehe's answer:

My objective is to have the plug-in asynchronously post work for the server side of my code (via an async write) and but have my own thread run the write and read completion handers, the latter being invoked for server side responses. I am trying to model the above scenario with a with two threads. One under the control of the io-context (representing my own thread) and the other not under the control of the io-context (representing the 3d application plug-in thread). Here is my feeble attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_(io_context_);
boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer_;

void read_completion_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
void write_completion_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

// "plug-in" (not part of io-context) calls this
void sendNextMsg()
{
    io_context_.run();
    while(true)
    {
        std::string msg;
        std::cout << "msg > " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> msg;
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(msg + "\n"), write_completion_handler);
    }
}

void write_completion_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if(ec)
    {
        std::cerr << "send failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        sendNextMsg();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Write succeeded" << std::endl;
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, receive_buffer_, "\n", read_completion_handler);
    }
}

void read_completion_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if(ec)
    {
        std::cerr << "receive failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        const char* data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(receive_buffer_.data());
        std::cout << "Server response: " << data << std::endl;
        receive_buffer_.consume(bytes_transferred);
    }
    
    sendNextMsg();
}

int main()
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    socket_.connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 7777), ec);
    
    if(ec)
    {
        std::cerr<< "[Connection error] " << ec.message() <<std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    std::thread{sendNextMsg}.detach();

    io_context_.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Outcome: application establishes a connection with the server but terminates after calling `sendNextMsg`.

Comment: "*Can one thread make an async write but another thread run its completion handler?*" Couldn't it do that by using a condition variable, mutex, or even atomic? You just have the other thread blocked on whatever it sets. I don't think there's a specific need for something in the API for that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with boost, but you could ask yourself the opposite question: how could the async completion logic gain control of the calling thread if it were to use that for the completion callback? --- In the (non-boost) contexts where I've used this, the callback always occurs on a thread pool thread, i.e. not the thread that made the request.

Answer (score 1):

> #### **Q.** Can one thread make an async write but another thread run its completion handler?

Yes. Asio is affords [concurrency without threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html).

You are in control. You choose how many threads do IO or post tasks. You choose how many execution contexts you use. You choose how many threads service these execution contexts. You choose where handlers may run.

As in all applications that deal with threads you may need to protect shared state from concurrent access. You choose whether that applies to your application, and how to ensure it (queues, strands, classic thread synchronization primitives etc).

Simplest of examples where one thread posts an operation, and the handler runs elsewhere. Assume

```
asio::io_context ioc;
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9993b56f1b77eb7)**

```
std::cout << "Posting from #" << thread_id << std::endl;
post(ioc, []{ std::cout << "Hello from #" << thread_id << std::endl; });
    
std::thread([&ioc] { ioc.run(); }).join();
```

Prints [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9993b56f1b77eb7)

```
Posting from #0
Hello from #1
```

Similarly,

```
asio::steady_timer tim(ioc, 1s);
std::cout << "Waiting from #" << thread_id << std::endl;
tim.async_wait([](error_code ec){ std::cout << ec.message() << " from #" << thread_id << std::endl; });
```

Prints [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8d1e2d177461cad)

```
Waiting from #0
Success from #1
```

Somewhat more interestingly:

```
asio::io_context ioc;
asio::thread_pool pool(10);
```

Here

```
auto handler = [](auto name, error_code ec) {
    sleep_for(1s);
    println("handler name:", name, " (ec:", ec.message(), ")");
};

asio::steady_timer tim(ioc, 1s);
tim.async_wait(bind(handler, "IO", _1));
tim.async_wait(bind_executor(pool, bind(handler, "Pool", _1)));

ioc.run(); // Note, on main thread!
```

Would print [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54329305d7de0595)

```
     0ms thread #0: Main enter
  2000ms thread #0: handler name:IO (ec:Success)
  2000ms thread #0: IO done, waiting for pool
  3001ms thread #1: handler name:Pool (ec:Success)
  3001ms thread #0: Main exit
```

Adding (optionally serialized) tasks on the pool:

```
auto task = [](auto name) {
    return [=] { sleep_for(1s); println("task: ", name, " done"); };
};

for (auto ex = pool.get_executor(); std::string i : {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"})
    asio::post(bind_executor(ex, task("Task " + i)));

for (auto strand = make_strand(pool); std::string i : {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"})
    asio::post(ioc, bind_executor(strand, task("Serial " + i)));
```

Prints [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/532526b658abc446):

```
     0ms thread #0: Main enter
  1000ms thread #1: task: Task 3 done
  1000ms thread #2: task: Task 4 done
  1000ms thread #3: task: Serial 6 done
  1000ms thread #4: task: Task 5 done
  1000ms thread #5: task: Task 1 done
  1000ms thread #6: task: Task 2 done
  2000ms thread #0: handler name:IO (ec:Success)
  2000ms thread #0: IO done, waiting for pool
  2001ms thread #3: task: Serial 7 done
  3001ms thread #7: handler name:Pool (ec:Success)
  3001ms thread #3: task: Serial 8 done
  4001ms thread #3: task: Serial 9 done
  5001ms thread #3: task: Serial 10 done
  5002ms thread #0: Main exit
```

> ***Note*** Although the "Serial" tasks are serialized on the pool, they are not guaranteed to run on a specific thread. In this case they happen to, because of how Asio optimizes strand execution if possible.

> #### **Q.** The first thread belongs to a framework (and therefore cannot be part of the async thread pool) but is the only thread that can create work.

This is not even necessarily accurate. E.g. you can invoke `poll_one()` regurlarly from a framework thread. Also, you can `asio::thread_pool::attach` from your own threads.

But these may not be relevant to your application.

> *The framework thread also makes the async write to a socket, but it
> immediately returns to running framework code, and is therefore
> unavailable. The second thread is created by my code is thus available
> to run the completion handler. Does boost asio have a way for the
> framework thread to initiate asynchronous IO but another thread run
> the resulting completion handler?*

There are many ways. For one, you could pass `future`s to the framework, which can await them where it requires the result, e.g.

```
 std::future<size_t> n = asio::async_read(s, buf, asio::use_future);
 // ... later:
 framework::handle_result(app_state, n.get());
```

> Note here `n.get()` may throw `system_error` on error

You can also post any packaged task like that:

```
 std::future<int> answer = post(ioc, std::packaged_task<int()> {
      sleep_for(100ms);
      return 42;
 });
```

Secondly, drawing from the above, you could

1. instantiate a "framework-side" execution context that you will not run blocking continuously, but instead `poll()`/`poll_one()` regularly.
2. post your completion to this execution context

> **Note** if you bind the executor to the handler at initiation, composed operations are required to run all intermediate handlers there. If this is not what you want/require, consider indirecting like e.g.

```
  asio::async_read(s, buf, [app_state](error_code ec, size_t n) {
      asio::dispatch(framework_executor, [=] {
          framework::handle_result(app_state, ec, n); 
      }
  });
```

> #### **Q.** If the async model does not draw a distinction between compute and IO threads and threads aren't preemptible (unless we are using coroutines) isn't there a real possibility that an IO completion handler, e.g. read, can be indefinitely prevented from running by threads doing compute?

Yes. This is solved by separating threads (like in the examples I already showed) and/or by (priority) queuing tasks so that you can throttle them.

### Listing For Reference

Anti bit-rot the combined listing of the initial examples above:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/532526b658abc446)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using boost::system::error_code;

namespace { // fancy tracing for illustration
    using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

    static int       next_thread_id = 0;
    thread_local int thread_id      = next_thread_id++;

    constexpr auto    now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static auto const start = now();
    static std::mutex console_mx;

    static void println(auto const&... a) {
        std::lock_guard lk(console_mx);
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms thread #" << thread_id << ":\t";
        (std::cout << ... << a) << std::endl;
    };
} // namespace

int main() {
    println("Main enter");

    asio::io_context ioc;
    asio::thread_pool pool(10);

    auto handler = [](auto name, error_code ec) {
        sleep_for(1s);
        println("handler name:", name, " (ec:", ec.message(), ")");
    };

    asio::steady_timer tim(ioc, 1s);
    tim.async_wait(bind(handler, "IO", _1));
    tim.async_wait(bind_executor(pool, bind(handler, "Pool", _1)));

    auto task = [](auto name) {
        return [=] { sleep_for(1s); println("task: ", name, " done"); };
    };

    for (auto ex = pool.get_executor(); std::string i : {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"})
        asio::post(bind_executor(ex, task("Task " + i)));

    for (auto strand = make_strand(pool); std::string i : {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"})
        asio::post(ioc, bind_executor(strand, task("Serial " + i)));

    ioc.run(); // Note, on main thread!
    println("IO done, waiting for pool");
    pool.join();
    println("Main exit");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your super comprehensive answer. It will take a few more reads for me to understand it all, but I must clarify that what I glibly referred to as a framework isn't really one but rather a third party 3d graphics application with plug-in capability. My client-side code is a plug-in that occasionally runs in a 3d application thread. Therefore I cannot rely on said thread doing anything after the flow of control has returned to the 3d application. This is the motivation for my first question and I will add a some more details to my question.

Comment: If the host application does not afford frequent callbacks (like idle processing, timer tick) then your only option would seem to have explicit queuing and polling thereof. Which does the job but is probably not what you were after here.

Comment: I went the refreshed timer route to keep `io_context::run()` from terminating. I could use this timer as a heartbeat.

Comment: "to keep io_context::run()" from terminating? For that you can just use a `work_guard`